# A way to make Laravel API private or restricted

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am now working on a development using Laravel and Vue.js. Vue files are included in Laravel, not separated. The problem is that I set up to send data to frontend(vue) by answering API calls. 
I've recently deployed my app to VPS, and now anybody can send GET/POST request to the API using curl command...
Would you please let me know how I can make the API private/restricted? I would like it to be accessed only by Vue. FYI, I used JWT-auth for the login system.

Comment: you cant in any way restrict who or what can send to your end points ... you can only verify the requests coming in, so make sure you are authenticating requests before responding to them

Comment: Thanks you very much for your comment!  regarding verification of the requests, maybe I can verify it using middleware? JWT is stored in a localstorage, so I guess I can set the middleware that rejects the requests if the person sending API requests doesn't have token in the storage..?

Comment: its a good start .. just make sure people get authenticated and things like that, you can't stop them from sending a request via any http client they want, but you can at least restrict how you respond to the requests

Comment: " you can't stop them from sending a request via any http client they want, but you can at least restrict how you respond to the requests" - Things are getting more and more clear to me. Thanks you Mr. lagbox! (>_<)

Comment: Authentication is a good start. Laravel can make sure the request coming in is from a known user before responding. Another option is that if this is not a public API and you don't want ANY endpoints to respond to outside requests, then you can set up your NGINX or Apache configuration to only allow requests from the same network. That will stop external requests before they even hits Laravel. If your webhost has firewall policies that you can use, that may be another route you can take.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, Mr. Maiorano!   "...set up Apache configuration to only allow requests from the same network" - I really love this idea...I would love to work on this configuration in order to get stronger app security.   I found this website "https://asawicki.info/news_1656_how_to_restrict_access_to_apache_server_to_local_machine", which I think is helpful. I will get right on it !

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the token in every request and in the api.php file you can protect routes by api middleware. i recommend you this serie of tutorials: https://blog.peterplucinski.com/setting-up-jwt-authentication-with-laravel-and-vue-part-1/

**How to protect routes**

```html
  Route::group([
          'middleware' => 'api',
          'prefix' => 'posts'
         ],
          function ($router) {
            Route::post('/', 'PostController@index');
         });

Another option:
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/posts','PostController@index');
```

**How to pass token in request the request**

```html
      axios.get('/api/posts', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.data = response.data
                }).catch(error => {

                })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The idea of adding header info really helps me. I have recently deployed my webapp to VPS, now staging environment. On a production environment I'm going to require only one login(jwt-auth), but since now is the staging, I also set up  Basic Auth in order to strengthen security for the time being. The problem is that when I checked the header info using chrome devtool, the property "Authorization" is used by Basic Auth, not by jwt-auth....I wanted the property to be like "Bearer XXX...".  Would you please let me know if it's possible to replace it with jwt?